# Dynamically setting header row text of a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi guys I have this function which dynamically creates gridviews and adds it to the page.
The datasource is set dynamically as well using a datatable. I want to set the header row text to that of the datatable's tablename. But the following is not working:

```
private void AddGridview(DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView gridView = new GridView();
        gridView.CssClass = "gridview";
        gridView.DataSource = dt;
        gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        gridView.ShowHeader = true;
        gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = dt.TableName;
        remittance.Controls.Add(gridView);
    }
}
```

It throws the following error at line 39:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

Line 37:             gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
Line 38:             gridView.ShowHeader = true;
Line 39:             gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = dt.TableName;
Line 40:             remittance.Controls.Add(gridView);
Line 41:         }
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = dt.TableName;

this doesnt work maybe because you havent called DataBind method.
gridView.DataBind();

Comment: i even tried that but now it does not show error and also does not set header

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = dt.TableName;
```

use this

```
gridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = dt.TableName;
```

Update:

```
private void AddGridview(DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
        GridView gridView = new GridView();
        gridView.CssClass = "gridview";
        gridView.DataSource = dt;
        gridView.DataBind();
        gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        gridView.HeaderRow.Visible = false;

        Table table = gridView.Controls(0);
        GridViewRow gvRow = new GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        TableCell newCell = new TableCell();

        newCell.ColumnSpan = dt.Columns.Count - 1;
        newCell.Text = dt.TableName;

        gvRow.Cells.Add(newCell);
        table.Rows.AddAt(0, gvRow);
        remittance.Controls.Add(gridView);
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to set header of the whole gridview not the columns.

Comment: I tried the following but I'm getting conversion error at          Table table = gridView.Controls(0);

Comment: are you sure you copied it correctly? I just tested the code and it works. Edited my post, included the whole function.

Comment: I'm 100% sure because at that line it says "Cannot implicitly convert type Control to Table". Do I need to explicitly cast it?

Comment: hmm, try it. I tried it in VB.NET it works fine, just converted the code to C#

Comment: yea that's why. In c# it needs to be like this: Table table = (Table)gridView.Controls[0]. Yet this code doesnt seem to set the header.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add columns first

```
    foreach(var col in table.Columns)
      gridview1.Columns.add(table.ColumnName);
```

Comment: the columns already exists in datatable and when i set the datasource to the datatable all columns appear